# Why jquery selector alway return true in If condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Why does this always return true?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" value="&controls=0">Hide Controls
```

```js
if ($('input[name=c1]:checked')){ 
    var controls = $('#c1').val();  
} else { 
    var controls = ""; 
}
alert(controls);
```

Is it a problem with value? But as you see I need a value...

Comment: Selectors alway is true. Use `$('input[name=c1]').is(':checked')` instead.

Comment: Why length I don't get it? @billyonecan

Comment: Yeah i got that I didn't understand why you said length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery selector return an object and selector object alway is true.

If you want to check existence of element, you can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method or [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

```
if ($("input[name=c1]").is(":checked"))
// Or 
if ($("input[name=c1]:checked").length)
```

Comment: Why did all of us got -1 I do not understand though. I am new to stackoverflow and this is just really annoying.

Comment: @MichalJarnot Some users don't like answers to a question that mainly due to the OP misunderstanding a basic mechanic. They generally will down-vote the question along with the answers, generally because they want quality answers and questions. I've up-voted the answers that are correct to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Someone gave me minus 1 so I decided to edit my answer:**

This is how you check if checkbox is checked:

```
$('input[name=c1]').is(':checked')
```

This is how you get value of a checkbox:

```
$('input[name=c1]').val();
```

Comment: Mohammad commented it first so I don't think it is okay to hit you as slover.

Comment: @MichalJarnot Some users tend to down-vote answers to questions they deem as poor, or already have an duplicate answer. In this case the down-vote was likely because you only included code in the answer, as there is no explanation why your code is correct or why the OP's code is wrong. Although it was edited, it's not likely the user came back to check yet to see if the quality of this answer has changed.

Comment: I probably should have seen that coming. Thank you for explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the expression $('input[name=c1]:checked') returns an object,which is true.
    alert($('input[name=c1]:checked'));//[object Object]

And the object have a length property with a value of 0 or 1

The correct option is to check the length.It is necessary to check on him

```
if($('input[name=c1]:checked').length)
{
    var controls = $('#c1').val();
}else{
    var controls = "";
}
alert(controls);
```

https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/